# on page load (onload) I need a popup box to appear and than fade after 5 seconds

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I thought something like this might work but it's not giving me exactly what i need.

Here's what I'm trying right now.

```
<style type="text/css">
    #overlay
    {
        display:none;
    }
</style>
<script>
    $( document ).ready(function(){
        $('#overlay').fadeIn('fast').delay(15000).fadeOut('fast');
    });
</script>
<div id="overlay">
<script>
      $(function () {
          $('a').click(function(){
              window.open('/getting-started/feg-top-performers','mywindow','width=400,height=200,toolbar=yes, 
    location=yes,directories=yes,status=yes,menubar=yes,scrollbars=yes,copyhistory=yes, 
    resizable=yes')
          });
      });
</script>
</div>
```

Basically as soon as the page opens I want to populate an entire html page and than have that page (the popup) fade out after 5 seconds.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Wow... Where to start...

Comment: Firstly, what is happening exactly? Is your popup working?

Comment: I know i have a mix of jquery and javascript in there... it's a complete mess right now that's why i'm looking here... i know i can probably eliminate one or the other @fizzix

Comment: Why reinvent the wheel when you can just use something simple such as Bootstrap? I can create a simple example for you if you would like to go down this path?

Comment: currently not anymore.

Comment: Check my answer then. Should provide you with a good reliable cross browser, responsive solution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Create a very simple Bootstrap modal, then set a timeout for when you would like it to hide. Bootstrap Modals look fantastic and are very customizable. They also have great fade in and out animations. View all the documentation along with the events, methods and options [HERE](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals).

**jQuery:**

```
$('#overlay').modal('show');

setTimeout(function() {
    $('#overlay').modal('hide');
}, 5000);
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="modal fade" id="overlay">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Context here</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[**WORKING DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/WPnk9/)

PS. Don't forget to also include both bootstrap.js and bootstrap.css within your project if you would like to go down this path. You can use the remote CDN files [HERE](http://www.bootstrapcdn.com/), or download them and include them within your project [HERE](http://getbootstrap.com/).

Comment: thank you.. that is one sexy looking modal. Appreciate it. ; ]

Comment: Does this look right?  $( document ).ready(function() {
$('#overlay').modal('show');

setTimeout(function() {
    $('#overlay').modal('hide');
}, 5000);
});

Answer (score 0):

Add this code to the and of :

```
setTimeout(function () { win.close();}, 5000);
```

There seem to be missing in your code

Answer (score 0):

Your window pops out of the DIV. Applying CSS to the DIV containing the script tag which opened the window will not effect the popup because it is no longer contained in the DIV - it has "popped up" and out of that DIV's spot.

What you'll need to do is use Javascript to apply CSS to the window itself (which can only be done if both pages are on the same site, mwhich they are in this case). Something like this assuming JQuery was called (untested code, merely a starting point for you to work with).

```
      $(function () {
          $('a').click(function(){
              NewWin=window.open('/getting-started/feg-top-performers','mywindow','width=400,height=200,toolbar=yes, 
    location=yes,directories=yes,status=yes,menubar=yes,scrollbars=yes,copyhistory=yes, 
    resizable=yes')
          });
var overlayopacity = 1;
var overlayinterval = window.setInterval("if(overlayopacity>0){overlayopacity-=0.1;}else{overlayinterval=window.clearInterval(overlayinterval);}NewWin.document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].style.opacity=overlayopacity;", 500);
      });
```