# How to load notification alert on top right corner without click of button in bootstrap or php?

Tags: php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have implemented successfully notification alert using bootstrap when user press or click of the button but I am looking a way to load alert in the same way without a click of the button. I want it on the page load.

**Below is the code:**

```
  <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">
           <button class="btn btn-default btn-block" onclick="demo.showNotification('top','left')">Top Left</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <button class="btn btn-default btn-block" onclick="demo.showNotification('top','center')">Top Center</button>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
                <button class="btn btn-default btn-block" onclick="demo.showNotification('top','right')">Top Right</button>
       </div>
</div>
```

I try `onload` but it doesn't work for me. if anyone has a better idea or something or better way then it would be great.

Comment: How did you try onload?  If you tried to put onload on the buttons that would not work as buttons do not have load events.

Comment: i use it on body

Comment: body onload="demo.showNotification('top','right')" ?

Comment: yes, the same way that you post above

Comment: Where there any errors in the console when you tried it like that?

Comment: I got a blank screen, seems  nothing works

Comment: F12 to open your developer tools, go to Console and look for any errors in that situation

Comment: ohky can I load something like this?  if(condition){echo "<div onload='demo.showNotification('bottom','left')' ></div>";
                                                            
                                                        }

Comment: Div do not have `load` events.  Only things like the window, iframes, or images have load events.  You could, however, echo a simple `<script>demo.showNotification(...)</script>` at the end of your page if you wanted to

Comment: soory not very much know about events

Comment: yep its works, but i am looking for embed this into php if condion

Comment: `if (condition){ echo "<script>....</script>" }`  so do it, :)

Comment: nops its not works, but thankyou for your efforts to help me sir

Answer (score 2):

(Answer to " ...but i am looking for embed this into php if condion" comment ... I cant write comments this time, Im newbie)

You can add a data attribute ([Use_data_attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes)) to your html element, what contains a flag.

```
<div class="col-md-3">
       <button id="top_left" class="btn btn-default btn-block" data-condition="<?php echo isset($var) ? 'true' : 'false'; ?>">Top Left</button>
</div>
```

You can access to this data in your js, and use it in statements, like:

```
var topLeftButton = document.querySelector('#top_left'); //Or build some logic, if you dont want use ids ...

if (topLeftButton.dataset.condition === 'true') {
    //do stuff

    //Furthermore, you can modifiy these datas from your js:
    topLeftButton.dataset.condition = 'false'; //so now, you turned off this flag
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following to get the notification on page load using jquery and Bootstrap

```js
$('#overlay').modal('show');

setTimeout(function() {
    $('#overlay').modal('hide');
}, 5000);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="modal fade" id="overlay">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Your heading goes here.. </h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Your content body goes here..</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

For further details refer this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23667130/9560041)

Also you can use the [noty.js](https://notifyjs.jpillora.com/) library which is a jQuery plugin to accomplish your task